# How do you use the new Facebook "download everything you’ve ever posted" feature?

Tags: facebook, export

I read about this in [the press](http://www.thestar.com/news/world/article/871599--facebook-announces-new-applications-gives-users-more-power) today, but can't find it anywhere within Facebook. Perhaps the feature isn't live yet? I've tried clearing cache and reloading, but don't know where I should be looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in [Account → Account Settings](https://register.facebook.com/editaccount.php), near the end of the page. Here's a [video about how to use it and where to find it](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150292657680484), but keep in mind that the option hasn't been rolled out to everyone yet, so you might not see it right now.